# Error: Invalid PathExpression when using Left Join with Count with Query-Builder in Symfony3 ( Doctrine2)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have an entity `Client` and `Facture` , Each `Client` has many `Facture` (:ManyToOne relation using a Foreign Key represented by `Facture->Clientid` ,
I want to List all `Client`s along with the number of `Facture` he has.

```
   ////////////////////////////////
   // id //  name   // factures  //
   ////////////////////////////////
   // 2  // someone // 16        //
   ////////////////////////////////
```

The SQL logic I am trying to achieve will be something like this :

```
SELECT c.name as name , f.client_id, Count(*) as factures
FROM facture as f INNER JOIN client as c
ON f.client_id = c.id 
WHERE f.client_id != 0 AND c.state = 1
GROUP BY c.id
```

What I did so far using query builder is the following on my `FactureRepository` which only recognizes `Facture` Entity.

```
public function findactivityList()
{  
return $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
->select('f.clientId','count(f.clientId) as factures','c.name')
->leftJoin('servicomBundle:FComptet ','c','WITH' ,'f.clientId = c.id')
->where('f.clientId != 0')
->andWhere('c.state = 1')
->groupBy('f.clientId')
->getQuery()
->execute()
;     
}
```

And I get this error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'clientId, count(f.clientId)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this:

```
->select('f.clientId','count(f.clientId) as factures','c.name')
```

to this:

```
->select('IDENTITY(f.clientId)','count(f.clientId) as factures','c.name')
```

You can use the IDENTITY function to select the foreign key IDs in a query